# how to gettext in listview

Tags: android, listview, gettext

How to `gettext` in `listview` `OnItemClickListener`??

I can't get text in listview toast work.but  `gettext();` not work

This is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int position, long id) {
          // ListView Clicked item index
          int itemPosition = position;

          //parent.getChildAt(position - listView.getLastVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.listView1);   
          String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

          //???????????????????????????.getText().toString();

          // Show Alert 
          Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Position :" + itemPosition + " ListItem: " + itemValue,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
          ).show();
        }
      });
```

Comment: can you post your model class or you can say data that you are sending to your ListView Adapter?

Comment: BTW why are you written `SuppressWarnings(unused")`?

Comment: please explain quetion properly

Comment: post your complete code. Are you using custom adapter or the default one?

Comment: sir,this is my adapter          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
         
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just type this code and import textview in your project

```
 String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
 String values=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long      id){

           TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblId);
           String s = textView.getText().toString();
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your id "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for taking the time to write an answer to this question. I already took the liberty to improve on the code formatting of your post, but you can further improve it: It is always a good idea to write a few words of explanation in addition to any code you put in your answer. It is especially helpful to explain why and how your code solves the initial problem. You can easily [edit] your answer to add this explanation, I suggest you do so. This will help OP and anybody else with the same question to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to get the id of the textView from the view parameter like this

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

TextView textView =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.Id.YourTextViewId);
String str=textView.getText();

}
```

Comment: take textview for set your text

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> view, View v, int position, long arg3) {
ListView l = (ListView) view;
String s = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the text from the view. Get it from the dataset `values`, which you used to bind the data to the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
String itemValue = values[position];
Toast.makeText(YourActivty.this, "Clicked " + itemValue + " at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```